# Cannot load fixture

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Iam having a problem with loading a fixture in django. I created a fixture with:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --format=json >website/fixtures/webste
```

Now when loading it with

```
./manage.py loaddata website/fixtures/webste
```

I get the error:

```
python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py:225: UserWarning: No fixture named 'webste' found.
  warnings.warn("No fixture named '%s' found." % fixture_name)
```

Although if I enter

```
nano website/fixtures/webste
```

it opens the correct file. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is

```
./manage.py loaddata webste
```

Assuming website is an installed app in your django project.

[1] [LoadData documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out myself: the file needs to contain an extension that tells django the serialization-format. So I renamed the file to "webste.json" and then the above command does work.